# python - start a thread if it's not already running

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multithread program where one of the functions I'm running is overlapping itself.
Here's an example:

```
import threading

def numbers(num):
    for i in range(0, num):
        print(i)

def main():
    threading.Thread(target=numbers, args=[1000]).start()

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

I want this to run until the user quit for example.

In this example I want it to print all the numbers from 0 to num (0 to 1000) but it prints something like this:

```
5
2
3
1
2
0
3
4
5
16
4
0
7
1
2850
1
6
7292
8
6
3
9
10
40
1
237
5
6
10
8
9
1111
03
4
3
```

As I see it it's starting the thread even if it's already running so it's overlapping itself.

My question is if there is a way to not start a thread if it's already running so it will print 0 to 1000 and then starts again from 0 to 1000 repeatedly,
but keep it as a thread so the rest of the program will continue running while it is counting?

Comment: start the main thread just once, then inside of that, in an infinite loop start your 2nd thread, and use `.join` to wait for the thread to finish, before starting it again.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that the main function is running lots of other functions.
it's not in the code here but there are more functions that runs simultaneously and in loop. so I have to run main in While true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is_alive property to start a thread only if previous one has finished running.

```
import threading

def numbers(num):

    for i in range(0, num):
        print(i)


current_thread = None
while True:
    if current_thread is None or not current_thread.is_alive():
        current_thread = threading.Thread(target=numbers, args=[100])
        current_thread.start()

    # do something else
```

Comment: This is getting close to what I'm looking for, it's working simultaneously with the other functions but the only promlem is that when the user change functionality this function is not released, it's still counting numbers

Comment: Ok I see now. You can keep the newly created thread in a variable and examine call its `is_alive()` method to check whether it is still running or not. And if it is not no running anymore, start a new one.

Comment: Thanks man! it worked!
With a little change to match my code it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call `threading.Thread(target=main).start()` a new Thread will be created and will be started. If you want to wait until the thread ends, you must use `.join` as follows:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=main).start()
t.join()
```

This, inside the `while True` will create infinite threads, but waiting for one to the other to finish.