# How do I start a thread only if the thread is not running for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to start create a thread to run a process (task function), but only creating the thread if the thread is not already running, and run only once. The main.py will be refreshed regularly and trigger the thread process to run in the background. This is so that I can save on compute resources. For example, if users refresh my page 3 times, the process goes on to run 3 threads, but I am trying to do so it only run once within the 10 seconds(during sleep). I just need the first time to work and trigger the thread/task and ignore subsequent triggers. I have created a script that I think should be working but it runs tasks every time main() runs, when it shouldn't.

I have created a try except to check if the current_thread is existing, if it is existing to check if its not running with the 'is_alive()' method, and if not to ignore(and not proceed) if it exists and still "is_alive()". If the exception triggers, the current_thread does not exist and the script proceeds to start a new thread (current_thread). Based on the logic in the script, It looks like current_thread.is_alive() is not working since I have a thread running but its still triggering new current_thread.start().

```
import time
import threading

def task():
    print ('start task')
    time.sleep(10)
    print ('task complete')

current_thread = threading.Thread(target=task)

def main():

    try:
        if not current_thread.is_alive():
            current_thread.start()
            current_thread.join()
    except UnboundLocalError as e:
        current_thread.start()
        current_thread.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While I found a answer that is related (it only runs a new thread when the old one finishes running), the script is not very useful since it runs infinitely, while I only want the thread to run one time. [python - start a thread if it's not already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032520/python-start-a-thread-if-its-not-already-running).

Any help on what I am missing or what can be done to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about.  When you run the script, main() is called once.  At that point, current_thread is not running since you have not called its start() method.  So current_thread.is_alive() is False.  The try:except: block does nothing, because there is no unbound local.  After starting the thread, you immediately call thread.join(), which will stop the main thread until the second thread is done.  Then the program exits.  That's all there is, and it doesn't seem to connect with your question.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean variable to keep track of whether or not you've started the thread.

```
import time
import threading

def task():
    print ('start task')
    time.sleep(10)
    print ('task complete')

def main():
    current_thread = threading.Thread(target=task)
    started = False
    for _ in range(12):
        if not started:
            started = True
            current_thread.start()
        time.sleep(1.0)
        print("Main loop...")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this is not what I am looking for, your script runs the thread 12 times in succession and during then, I cant run other tasks in my main() there are some other tasks inside of the main function that needs to run in parallel. I am looking for a script that can run other tasks in main while the task thread is running concurrently. The task thread should only activate once main() is triggered and main contains other tasks should be able to run while the threaded process is running.

Comment: I think that part of the original requirement, the boolean variable suggestion that checks if the threaded process is running and stop any subsequent ones from starting, is what I am looking for but I cant seem to think of a way to stop additional threads from spawning while one is active. I am not sure if the loop helps but it keeps other tasks from running while the loop is active.

Comment: The script does NOT run the thread 12 times in succession.  It starts the second thread exactly once, because the boolean variable is set to True before it starts the second thread.  Subsequent passes through the loop do not start the thread again.  Did you run the program?  You don't need to "think of a way to stop additional threads from spawning" because that is the whole point - it's already done.  Obviously, a real program will do something other than sit in a loop and sleep.